# Two (or more) parallel (sub-)TLDs that are retained when surfing the site / dynamically set the site address?

Tags: url-rewriting, site-url

I am running a site for a German NGO under the domain `sub.example.org`.
Recently, I added `sub.example.ch` for its Swiss spin-off.

Both (sub-)domains are pointing to the same physical location, a WP install (*not* multisite).

I have it setup such that `sub.example.ch/register`, for instance, will correctly show the content found under `sub.example.org/register`.

However, when a Swiss visitor surfs the site using regular on-site links, he or she will inevitably end up on the "regular" domain, since those utilize the "WordPress address" (or "site address") as defined in general settings, either via `get_home_url` or `get_site_url()` (or their less-deep `get_bloginfo()` equivalents).

*Ideally*, I'd like the visitor to keep surfing under the domain that he or she used to reach the site. Hence, I suppose I'd have to somehow filter the return value of the mentioned functions. A filter, which, as far as I know, does not exist.

1. Does anybody have experience with this sort of thing and a decent solution handy?
2. Is this maybe a dumb idea and I should let it go in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could filter the option requests for the host.

In your `wp-config.php` *below* the line …

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

… add the following lines:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_home', 'set_current_host' );
add_filter( 'pre_option_siteurl', 'set_current_host' );

function set_current_host()
{
    return 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

`add_filter()` is not available earlier, and you should keep such code in your `wp-config.php`. I don’t know if there are side effect or cases where it doesn’t work. Should not happen, but test it thoroughly.

Comment: I will test it thoroughly for sure. Now.

Comment: 12 hours later: Works without exception. That the value would have to come from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is pretty straightforward, that would have been my approach too. While this was being answered, I was attempting to utilize the `bloginfo_url` filter from a plugin. Did *not* do the job. To put the filtering in the configuration file, however, I would have tried after days of contemplating only, if at all. The outcome of this solution surpassed my wildest expectations: Not only do links resolve nicely, login credentials work as well and even the back-end does not choke! Awesomeness!

Comment: Both (sub-)domains are pointing to the same physical location, a WP install (not multisite). Do do so, you need to log in your hosting service. When you create a subdomain, domain you have to specify a document root. Here, select the same path as your main Domain with WP installed on it. Then, add the code. Working perfectly, try to think about SEO ( canonical and alternate tags)