# How to make my wordpress site responds for 2 domains

Tags: customization, plugins, ssl

I have a Wordpress Woocommerce site running on www.mydomain.com.br and I'd like it to also respond for the domain srougi.biz/mydomain because my return page (page that users go after payment) must have SSL.

I only have SSL for srougi.biz not, for mydomain.com.br, so my return page would be https://srougi.biz/mydomain/return.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96684/two-or-more-parallel-sub-tlds-that-are-retained-when-surfing-the-site-dyna)?

Answer (score 0):

This question may be better served on Serverfault, look into setting up a domain alias or 302 'masked' redirect. However the point of an SSL is to verify a domain or a business entity so this might be moot. I would pop over to namecheap or cheapSSL and buy a cheap SSL cert.