# Override Wordpress theme url

Tags: site-url

I have a site where I used `http://example.com`, but if I change my site URL to `http://example.co.uk` or `http://examplesite.co.uk` which are all same site.

If I changed anything in the above urls it should override theme url.

Currently it is showing from the database value.

I used

```
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
```

but for theme &plugin url it is not working it shows `http://example.co.uk`

I want as `http://example.com` if user types the same

Comment: Please always care about formatting your questions properly. Thanks.

Comment: This _should_ work (technically at least, same site at multiple domains is bad idea for SEO and stuff) form what I remember. Can you access admin at alternate URLs and do you see domain changing in Settings > General ?

Comment: I've had a similar requirement to fulfill a few months back. You might care to refer to [this excellent answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96684/two-or-more-parallel-sub-tlds-that-are-retained-when-surfing-the-site-dyna).

Comment: thanks for answering. but it is working for bloginfo('url') & not for bloginfo('template_url'). Any ideas?

Comment: can you tell me also for plugins url. Except plugin url all are working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: plugins shows the default url and can i know how i use current url. example) example.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/name/file/file.css should be example.com/wp-content/plugins/name/file/file.css if the user enters example.com. But it shows as the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment I pointed you to an existing answer that I figured would solve your problem.

You replied

> thanks for answering. but it is working for bloginfo('url') & not for bloginfo('template_url'). Any ideas?

The answer I pointed you to is easily adaptable for that:

In your `wp-config.php` file, *after* (!) `require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';` do the following:

```
function wpse114490_set_template_uri( $dir )
{
    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ) {
        $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $dir = str_replace( 'example.com', $domain, $dir );
    }
   return $dir;
}
add_filter( 'template_directory', 'wpse114490_set_template_uri' );
add_filter( 'template_directory_uri', 'wpse114490_set_template_uri' );
add_filter( 'stylesheet_directory', 'wpse114490_set_template_uri' );
add_filter( 'stylesheet_directory_uri', 'wpse114490_set_template_uri' );
```

This is assuming that `example.com` is the value set in your settings/DB.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the relocate method:**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method

(Also, if you haven't, replace the URL in MySQL by using http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` write hard coded value and check if it is working.